# update multiple rows, with an increasing value.(not autoinc.)

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok. I am trying to update multiple rows with an value that increases for each row.

```
Update table set value=(.......) where update_row = something...
```

Is it possible?
the following rows:

```
ID:name:value
1:name1:0
2:name2:0
4:name4:0
5:name5:0
7:name7:0
9:name9:0
```

after update i want it to be:

```
1:name1:1
2:name2:2
4:name4:3
5:name5:4
7:name7:5
9:name9:6
```

And... Is it possible to order the update in some way so that the value that increases is in the correct order, like above? Using auto increment is not an option. i have to do this manually....

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like

```
set @rownum := 0;   
Update table set value=(@rownum := @rownum + 1)
where update_row = something...
```